# SplashScreen: AsyncTask + ProgressBar + rotar dispositivo, Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Tengo una splashcreen donde ejecuto un proceso background con `AsyncTask`, cuando roto el dispositivo la tarea anterior continua, pero se vuelve a iniciar otra vez.

Me estoy leyendo de como afrontar el problema, de la mejor manera posible, es decir, evitar malas costumbres/prácticas, como poner la actividad en modo persistente o bien capturar `android:configChanges` con el `AndroidManifest`, el mejor método que indican es usar `weakReference` pero no ser como implementarlo con el AsyncTask.

Además me gustaría mostrar un `ProgressDialog` pero también me encuentro que si roto el dispositivo desaparece.

Me estoy mirando: [retaining-objects-across-config-changes](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html)

Tengo lo siguiente para hacer las pruebas:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private myAsyncTask handlerTask;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();

                handlerTask = new myAsyncTask();
                handlerTask.execute();

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    private void largeTask() {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            //e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }


    private class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {


        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            //Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground: ");
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                largeTask();
                Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: " + i);
                publishProgress(i * 10);

                if (isCancelled()) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "isCancelled:  TRUE");
                    break;
                }

            }

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            //Log.i(TAG, "onProgressUpdate: ");
            int progreso = values[0];
            Log.d(TAG, "onProgressUpdate: " + values[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute: ");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute: ");

            if (result) {
                //pDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Tarea finalizada!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            Log.w(TAG, "onCancelled: ");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Tarea cancelada!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }


}
```

Cada vez que se pulsa el `fabButton` ejecuta la tarea, si se rota el dispositivo y se vuelve a pulsar el `fabButton` lanza otra tarea, si estuviera en onCreate solo en rotar la lanzaría de nuevo, es lo que quiero evitar, además añadir un `dialogFragment` con progreso horizontal.

Comment: has considerado deshabilitar la rotacion? :)

Comment: @jirungaray si, me parece que es lo que haré, igualmente es una splascreen

Comment: Me parece que ya he encontrado la solución, el error que cometía inicialmente es que no creaba el TaskFragment en un archivo externo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siguiendo el articulo [Handling Configuration Changes with Fragments](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html) y adaptando para que use las librerías de soporte.

El método que comenta es crear un `AsyncTask` que extienda de un `Fragment` y en la `SplashScreen` implementar los métodos del `AsyncTask`

Para prevenir que al rotar el dispositivo se vuelve a lanzar la tarea, se comprueba si el fragmento está cargado en memoria, solo se crea uno de nuevo la primera vez.

**Crear TaskFragment.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public class TaskFragment extends Fragment {

    interface TaskCallbacks {
        void onPreExecute();
        void onProgressUpdate(int percent);
        void onCancelled();
        void onPostExecute();
    }

    private TaskCallbacks mCallbacks;
    private DummyTask mTask;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        if (context instanceof Activity){
            mCallbacks = (TaskCallbacks) (Activity) context;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Retain this fragment across configuration changes.
        setRetainInstance(true);

        // Create and execute the background task.
        mTask = new DummyTask();
        mTask.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }

    private class DummyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            if (mCallbacks != null) {
                mCallbacks.onPreExecute();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... ignore) {
            for (int i = 0; !isCancelled() && i <= 100; i++) {
                SystemClock.sleep(500);
                publishProgress(i);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... percent) {
            if (mCallbacks != null) {
                mCallbacks.onProgressUpdate(percent[0]);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            if (mCallbacks != null) {
                mCallbacks.onCancelled();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void ignore) {
            if (mCallbacks != null) {
                mCallbacks.onPostExecute();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SplashScreen.java**

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TaskFragment.TaskCallbacks {

    private static final String TAG_TASK_FRAGMENT = "task_fragment";
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private TaskFragment mTaskFragment;

    private  TextView labelProgress;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mTaskFragment = (TaskFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(TAG_TASK_FRAGMENT);

        // If the Fragment is non-null, then it is currently being
        // retained across a configuration change.
        if (mTaskFragment == null) {
            mTaskFragment = new TaskFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(mTaskFragment, TAG_TASK_FRAGMENT).commit();
        }

        labelProgress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label_progress);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressUpdate(int value) {
        value = value;
        Log.d(TAG, "onProgressUpdate: " + String.valueOf(value));
        labelProgress.setText( String.valueOf(value) + "%");

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCancelled: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute: ");
    }
}
```

### Versión con progressBar

Para añadir un progressBar

**En el layout.xml**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label_progress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Hello World!" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/label_progress"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="21dp" />
```

**SplashScreen.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TaskFragment.TaskCallbacks {

    private static final String TAG_TASK_FRAGMENT = "task_fragment";
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private TaskFragment mTaskFragment;

    private  TextView labelProgress;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private static int oldValue;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mTaskFragment = (TaskFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(TAG_TASK_FRAGMENT);

        // If the Fragment is non-null, then it is currently being
        // retained across a configuration change.
        if (mTaskFragment == null) {
            mTaskFragment = new TaskFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(mTaskFragment, TAG_TASK_FRAGMENT).commit();
        }

        labelProgress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label_progress);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            onProgressUpdate(oldValue);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressUpdate(int value) {
        value = value;
        Log.d(TAG, "onProgressUpdate: " + String.valueOf(value));
        labelProgress.setText( String.valueOf(value) + "%");
        //mProgressBar.setProgress(value);

        ProgressBarAnimation anim = new ProgressBarAnimation(mProgressBar, oldValue, value);
        anim.setDuration(500);
        mProgressBar.startAnimation(anim);

        oldValue = value;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCancelled: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute: ");
    }


    public class ProgressBarAnimation extends Animation {
        private ProgressBar progressBar;
        private float from;
        private float  to;

        public ProgressBarAnimation(ProgressBar progressBar, float from, float to) {
            super();
            this.progressBar = progressBar;
            this.from = from;
            this.to = to;
        }

        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);
            float value = from + (to - from) * interpolatedTime;
            progressBar.setProgress((int) value);
        }

    }

}
```